# How can I display results within a certain area using Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I have a tkinter window that looks like the picture attached. I would like to display squares of equal size within the red square I drew and have text inside them. I also plan on making the widgets buttons that when clicked take the user to a link. But the main focus of this thread is creating a specifically sized frame and placing it in a specific area within the red frame and then placing widgets inside that new frame. How would I go across doing this?
[Tkinter window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxDMK.png)

I have tried creating a frame within my main frame and placing a widget inside it however the widget just vanished.
My code that handles frames looks like this

```
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("1800x1000")
IngredientList = []


frm_filter = tk.Frame(master=window, bg="red", height=500, width=300)
frm_main = tk.Frame(master=window, bg="green", height=1000, width=1000)

frm_display = tk.Frame(master=frm_main, bg="blue", height=10, width=20)

frm_main.grid_propagate(False)
frm_filter.grid_propagate(False)

window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=75)
window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=200)

#edit

frm_filter.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
frm_main.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
frm_display.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="nsew")
```

Comment: You haven't use any layout manager (`pack()`, `grid()` or `place()`) on the frames, so they are invisible.

Comment: thanks I have gridded the frames now, however only the filter and main frame appear, not the display frame

Comment: I can see the blue frame `frm_display` at the top-left corner of the green frame `frm_main`.

Comment: I can't see it anywhere.

Comment: [This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wARN7.png).

Comment: thats odd since it doesn't appear anyway at all for me even when full screened